# place javascript function result inside html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to insert return value of a function to a tags attribute value in html

```
<video width="400" controls="controls">
    <source src="XXXXX" />
</video>


function returnVideoLink() {
    return "aa.mp4";
}
```

in the above codes i want to get the functions return value in the above video tags src field marked as XXXX

Comment: $("video source").attr("src", returnVideoLink());

Comment: Note that you'll need jquery (http://jquery.com/) for the above to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this jQuery code:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function returnVideoLink() {
        return "aa.mp4";
    }

    $(function() {
        var src = returnVideoLink();
        $('source').attr('src', src);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @mohamad shiralizadeh what code should be used in the video source src field

Comment: You can add anything as that will get replaced once jQuery code executes.